# TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, router, middleware

I am developing a simple API using JWT authorization, and by trying to make a verify middleware.
Apparently, im getting an error while exporting the middleware function:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined`

middlewares/auth.js:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers['authorization'];
  console.log('Authorization token => ', token);
  if (!token) {
    res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' });
  } else {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    req.verified = verified;
    next();
  }
};
```

routes/user.js:

```
const authMiddleware = require('../middlewares/auth');

router.use(authMiddleware());
```

Comment: this will solve your issue `app.use(authMiddleware())`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `req.headers['authorization']` use `req.query['authorization']`